# Insert into SQL Server DB statement Date Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this insert statement that is failing, throwing this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

Here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO JOBR_GENERIC (ID, NUM_ATTR1, STR_ATTR1, TYPE, PLANT_ID,
                          MATERIAL_NUMBER, ORDERNO, LOTNO, QTY, DATE_ATTR1, 
                          STR_ATTR2, NUM_ATTR2, NUM_ATTR3, NUM_ATTR4, 
                          STR_ATTR3, NUM_ATTR5, NUM_ATTR6, NUM_ATTR7, 
                          NUM_ATTR9, NUM_ATTR10, NUM_ATTR11, DATE_ATTR2, 
                          DATE_ATTR3, DATE_ATTR4, NUM_ATTR12, NUM_ATTR13, STR_ATTR4, JOBR_TS) 
VALUES (153322, 401129, '901', 'A', 'A85', 
        '8ALD160', '', '6666666A', 8, CONVERT(DATETIME, '24/06/2017 00:00:00', 120),  
        'Test', 1, 9, 1, 
        '', 36, 99999999, 0, 
        109, 0, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/06/2018 16:08:26:397', 120), 
        CONVERT (DATETIME, '15/06/2018 16:08:26:397', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '', 120), 0, 0, 
        'A85', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-07-05 12:31:34', 120))
```

Comment: FYI I changed your incorrect MySQL tag to SQL Server as this is clearly a SQL Server bit of code (and error). Please check that you use the appropriate tags for the product you're referring to, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code `CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/06/2018 16:08:26:397', 120)` is wrong (as are most of your other convert statements).

The `120` is telling SQL to expect the date to be formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 for the list of formats.

Make sure your text format matches what you're telling the server to expect. `103` (matching `dd/mm/yyyy`) will  work for you for the example above:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/06/2018 16:08:26:397', 120)
```

I would also suggest using a consistent date format throughout your query, rather than mixing and matching as you do now. A consistent approach will make it easier to maintain your code and to spot mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You have no need for the conversions.  Just use strings in the appropriate types.

(2) Converting an empty string to a date/time doesn't make sense.  Just use `NULL` or leave the column out of the `insert`.  So:

```
VALUES (153322,  401129, '901', 'A', 'A85', '8ALD160', '', '6666666A', 8,
        '2017-06-24 00:00:00', 'Test', 1, 9, 1, '', 36, 99999999,  
        0, 109, 0, 0, '2018-06-15 16:08:26:397',
        '2018-06-15 16:08:26:397', NULL, 0, 0, 'A85',
        '2018-07-05 12:31:34'
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you are attempting to use is the ODBC YYYY-MM-DD format, however, you have a date parameter in the format of DD/MM/YYYY. This will not work.